# how to set up sublime text keymap to xcode

Tags: xcode, sublimetext3, hotkeys, keymapping

I'm used to sublime text keymap and now I'm trying to write code in xcode, but I can't get used to hotkeys in xcode. Google bard advised to download .xml file with sublime text hotkeys but I couldn't find that file. Is there any way to use Sublime Text Keymap in Xcode?

Comment: Sublime keymap files are not XML files; you can use `View Package File` from the command palette in Sublime, enter `Default OSX keymap` and hit enter to see the file. However, the bindings are application specific so all you're going to get is a list of what keys do what things in Sublime, which you would have to map manually in XCode unless it has some sort of import tool.

Comment: This? https://medium.com/%E5%B7%A5%E7%A8%8B%E5%B1%8D-software-zombie/mac-xcode-keybinding-customize-base-on-sublime-text-key-binding-a4c567b1157b